# Get instance name in ColdFusion 10

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How can I get the name of the ColdFusion instance ("cfusion" for example) in **ColdFusion 10**?

Pre-10 you could do so by using the jrun java object:

```
<cfobject action="create" type="java" class="jrunx.kernel.JRun" name="jr">

#jr.getServerName()#
```

But since Jrun has been replaced by Tomcat I need to find a new way of getting the instance name.

I know it can be done using the admin api but that does not work for me because of security issues.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Determining which instance is serving your request. We have multiple instances serving the same app behind a load balancer. I want to know which CF instance is handling my request because it can instance01, instance02 or instance03.

Comment: Jan, I'm curious why you say there are "security issues" that keep you using the Admin API to solve this problem, as Marcin also showed. It's the ready solution for CF10, since as you say you can't rely on the JRun object any more. 

I could understand if you thought all Amin API methods require logging in (with the login method of the administrator.cfc in the Admin API), but as can be seen in Marcin's example, this is not one of those methods. It should work for anyone.

I really am sincerely curious what would make it "not work" for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look in the server scope.  There is a value at server.coldfusion.rootdir.  On CF10 this is the directory of the instance.  So for the "cfusion" instance on my Mac for example, this value is /Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion.  You could grab the last directory namd in the path and that is the name of the instance.  Not exactly elegant, but might get you what you need.

Comment: This seems to work. It's not the last dir in the multi-server setup but it is there: `C:\CF\servers\instance01\cfusion-ear\cfusion-war\WEB-INF\cfusion`

Comment: interesting.  could be a mac vs pc thing

Comment: My local Windows stand-alone setup is this: `C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion` and `C:\ColdFusion10\secondInstance` So it seems to be a stand-alone vs. multi-server thing.

Comment: Well, CF 10 doesn't have the same "multiserver" setup that CF9 and previous had.  It has the "server" install and the WAR/EAR install.  Your license determines if you can setup multiple instances when installed using "server" installation method.  Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 5):

There is a "runtime" component in the Admin API in CF10. You can get the instance name with this snippet of code:

```
var runtime = createObject("component", "CFIDE.adminapi.runtime");
instance = runtime.getInstanceName();
```

This should return the same value as `getServerName()` used to in the `jrunx.kernel.JRun` component.

Answer (score -5):

This should work:

```
<cfset inetAddressObj = createObject("java", "java.net.InetAddress") />
<cfset machineName = inetAddressObj.localhost.getCanonicalHostName() />
```

Comment: Alas, that returns the name of the machine, but I have multiple instances running on the _same_ machine. I need the name of the CF instance. But thanks for answering!

Comment: That's not the "instance" name - and that code works in any version to get the "friendly" name of the machine it's on.